# How can I get my submit button to work in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use Mailchimp with react to create a newsletter signup form. However I'm having the issue of the button I've created not working. I can enter information into the form but I cannot submit it. I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong. The code is below. Any explanation is appreciated.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const SubscribeForm = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // perform form submission here
  }

  return (
    <div id="mc_embed_signup">
      <form 
        action="https://eclipsecard.us8.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=apigoeshere&amp;id=listidhoeshere&amp;f_id=anotheridhere" 
        method="post" 
        id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" 
        name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" 
        className="validate" 
        target="_self"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
          <h2>Subscribe to Eclipse</h2>
          <div className="indicates-required">
            <span className="asterisk">*</span> indicates required
          </div>
          <div className="mc-field-group">
            <label htmlFor="mce-EMAIL">
              Email Address <span className="asterisk">*</span>
            </label>
            <input 
              type="email" 
              value={email} 
              name="EMAIL" 
              className="required email" 
              id="mce-EMAIL" 
              required
              onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
            <span id="mce-EMAIL-HELPERTEXT" className="helper_text"></span>
          </div>
          <div id="mce-responses" className="clear foot">
            <div className="response" id="mce-error-response" style={{ display: 'none' }}></div>
            <div className="response" id="mce-success-response" style={{ display: 'none' }}></div>
          </div>    
          <div style={{ position: 'absolute', left: '-5000px' }} aria-hidden="true">
            <input type="text" name="b_5dc03094f057ba65239f4c04b_1ef7f96bf7" tabIndex="-1" value="" />
          </div>
          <div className="optionalParent">
            <div className="clear foot">
              <input 
                type="submit" 
                value="Subscribe" 
                name="subscribe" 
                id="mc-embedded-subscribe" 
                className="button"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SubscribeForm;
```

Everything else seems to be working alright, it just appears to be an issue with how I've down the button, however I cannot identify a way to make it better or fix it.

Comment: Why did you add a custom handler and prevent the default action?

Comment: If you just want to submit the form like a normal html form, remove the `handleSubmit` that prevents the default behavior.

Comment: to be sure, you can enter into the input named `EMAIL` but can't get it with the `e.EMAIL` in submit? nor your `email` value is filled?

Comment: from what I see you're doing everything correctly, in react we have used to access form values using their state since before hooks existed, I would consider using the variable `email`, but what I see as unusal is the action, I think it's prevented with the prevent default, you need to use fetch I think, not sure, but hope this helps.